# How do I get started with ROS?

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where to get started.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9037/how-do-i-get-started-with-ros?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-23**:
related http://answers.ros.org/question/1350/im-new-to-ros-how-do-i-get-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start by looking at the [ROS tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [mwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/28/mwise/) with karma: 208 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Visit the getting started guide http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/StartGuide

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would also add to print the ROS development tools cheat sheet and have it taped somewhere in your field of view at work or home (that's what I did in the beginning :) )
Helps to flatten the learning curve. Especially rxgraph and rostopic.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Documentation?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ROScheatsheet.pdf

---

Originally posted by [Alper Aydemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/119/alper-aydemir/) with karma: 126 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3